# Whole number and rational number relationship

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer $ n $ such that$\frac {2n+3}{n-2}$ is a whole number.  I expressed the numerator as $2n-4+3+4$=$2 (n-2)+7$ Then the given expression reduces to $2+\frac {7}{n-2}$ . I got $ n=1$ $n=3$ $ n=-5$. Are there more values

Comment: One more value I think. . . $n-2$ must be a factor of $7$, there is a very simple factor of $7$ that you seem to have missed.

Answer (score 1):

$n-2|7$ i.e $7=t(n-2)$. Since $\{\pm 1, \pm 7\}$ are the only divisor of $7$ so possible choices for $n-2$ are $1, -1, 7, -7$ which says $n=3, 1, 9, -5$ are the only values for $n$.